# Why do php function json_decode fail if string contains the word undefined as a value?

Tags: php, javascript, json, dojo

I have this string, which is generated by dojo.toJson() function:

```
{"page":"accommodation task=viewList","language":undefined}
```

When decoding it with json_decode in php it returns null.

I already figured out that this is caused by the value undefined, but I am not sure if this is to be expected or if it is a bug. Is the above string not valid json? Why can't php just convert undefined to null?

I am using PHP 5.2.10

Comment: If it's dojo creating invalid JSON strings, as suggested by some answers, it might be worth noting that I'm using dojo 1.4.3, so it's possible this has been fixed in a later version...?

Comment: See my updated answer, it's still broken in Dojo 1.6.1 (the latest).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `undefined` is not valid [JSON](http://json.org/). JSON doesn't have the JavaScript concept of `undefined`. It does have `null`, which is vaguely similar, but the usual thing (for better or worse) is to simply omit properties whose values would be `undefined`.

I'm surprised if Dojo's `toJson` produces invalid JSON like that. You might consider using [Crockford's `JSON.stringify`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/) instead. If Dojo's `toJson` is really doing that, I'd report it as a bug to the Dojo team.

**Update**: Apparently someone [*did* report it to them](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/11433), and they closed it as invalid on the "garbage in, garbage out" theory. Not my project, but that's just totally *not* how I would handle properties with `undefined` values... I'd omit them or throw an exception.

**Update 2**: As you may know, the [ECMAScript 5th edition specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) defines a `JSON` object with `parse` and `stringify` which browsers are adding support for. The specification's definition of `JSON.stringify` says *"`undefined` values are not rendered"* (Section 15.12.3, Note 2) — e.g., the property should be omitted. Perhaps if you point that out to the Dojo team, they'll rethink their GIGO response to the bug report. Also note @Felix's comment below: They omit function references, which also can't be validly represented in JSON, but apply a different rule to `undefined`.

**Update 3**: Still broken in Dojo 1.6.1. Here's a [live test](http://jsbin.com/eruka4/3) of v1.6.0, which is the latest on the CDNs. I've also tested v1.6.1 and it's still broken there too. (Not going to post a test page hotlinking to their download section, though, that would be rude.)

Comment: Thanks, good answer. I'm using dojo 1.4.3, so if it hasn't been fixed in a later version I'll consider reporting it as a bug.

Comment: @jgivoni: No worries. I just added an update citing the new specification, which might help you get them to fix it.

Comment: That is interesting. There seems to be some kind of double standard here. A function reference is also not valid, [but omitted in the output](http://jsfiddle.net/UBZ39/). You are right, the same should be done for `undefined`.

Comment: I guess it comes down to whether the undefined value is rightly considered garbage. Since it's a part of javascript (ecmascript) I would expect to encounter it from time to time. Maybe dojo would provide a dojo.sanitizeForJson() that we could apply each time prior to using dojo.toJson()? Hell no, I'll look into Crockford's JSON.stringify first :-)

Comment: @jgivoni: JavaScript objects can have properties with values that are `undefined`, or function references, both of which are perfectly valid. JSON has no representation for either of those things. The behavior defined by the standard is to omit those properties, and that behavior was defined prior to the bug report listed above. Also, Crockford's `JSON.stringify` omits properties with `undefined` values, and as Crockford *defined* JSON, prior to the ECMAScript standard, his implementation would be definitive. Due respect to the Dojo folks, they just got it wrong. (We all do, sometimes.)

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the undefined to null in PHP on the server side, that fixes the immediate issue:

```
<?php
$json = '{"page":"accommodation task=viewList","language":undefined,"example": "This is an example of an occurence of undefined that remains"}';
$json = preg_replace( 
     '~undefined(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*")*[^"]*$)~', 'null', $json 
);

var_dump( json_decode( $json ) );
```

The better solution though would be to make sure 'undefined' will not appear in the JSON, as it is - indeed - invalid.

Comment: ...and if "undefined" appears in a quoted string? E.g., `{"msg": "The behavior shouldn't be undefined."}` ;-)

Comment: Excellent point indeed. Perhaps the str_replace call was a little naive, and a regular expression would do a better job?

Comment: Good luck with that. Matched quotes where escaping is an option are notoriously hard to handle with regular expressions. :-) As you say, the best thing is to prevent this from happening in the first place. (I'd do that by not using Dojo's `toJson`.)

Comment: Hehe, a bit too bold for me just to replace all ocurences of 'undefined' with 'null' :-) But hey, if you're the reckless type...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder @jgivoni Fixed that, this is less naive and will not replace any occurrence of "undefined" enclosed in quotes.